# Azure publishing error Flask Web App

Tags: python, visual-studio, azure

I have FLask Web app that i published as azure web app. Im getting this error. 
I created new resource, downloaded publishing profile and published it from visual studio using the downloaded file. Can someone else tell me what is Microsoft.cis.monitoring.query for? I tried to search around and only things that came up was related to cloud services/worker roles, which i dont believe im using in my project.
[image]

my project debug/release was set to "Any CPU".
Things ive tried based on similar questions on here:

> - changed debug/release to x32
> - changed debug/release to x64
> - changed debug/release to x86

i tried all three setttings. (build->configuration->platform) & (solution properties->platform target)

I initialized the webb app using +->web+mobile->web app
[image]

Comment: If you use VS to publish Python code on WebApp, you might be interested in reading this article from the PTVS team (Python Tools For Visual Studio): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/12/12/publish-to-azure-in-vs-2017/

Comment: I actually followed that site while publishing. Went back and re-read it all but no help.

Comment: @GiorgiTediashvili I doubt whether you created a cloud service on Azure portal and deploy your Flask App into it, or created a Flask Web Role from cloud service template in PTVS. Please refer to the PTVS wiki pages for [Web Project](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Web-Project) & [Cloud Service Project](https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/Cloud-Project) to know their differences and check your project & deployment carefully. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I'm going to republish the project I'm guessing based on the error somehow it may have deployed as cloud service instead of web app.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT i updated my post with a screenshot of azure portal on how i created my web app. Then i downloaded publish profile and published it via VS. this seems to be NOT a cloud service right?

Comment: @GiorgiTediashvili It's as Web App now. Any update after deployment?

Comment: seems like in my project on azure portal under bin there was a file 'python web role' created i went ahead and delete it and its fixed now, theres other errors but i believe this solves the questions.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you peterPan! Seems like my project somehow was including 'web role' file under project->bin i went ahead and delete and it ran fine. Azure was looking at my projet as a cloud service instead of a web app.